# Lattice package: add mean to boxplots

Tags: r, lattice, boxplot

I am trying to to create boxplots using the **lattice package** and add **mean values** to them. I noticed, depending on the method, the boxes are equal but the mean values are sometimes **wrong**.

It appears to be related to (not) using **panel = panel.superpose()**.

I attached a working example and images. For example the the first "box" (cyl = 4, vs = 0): there is only one value but the calculated mean is being drawn atop of it.

Does anybody understand what's going on there? Any help would be appreciated.

**Generally, when can panels simply be combined (p1) and when should panel.superpose be used (p2) to avoid such issues?**

Thank you.

```
library("datasets")
library("lattice")

df_1 <- mtcars

p1 <- bwplot(mpg ~ factor(vs) | factor(cyl), data = df_1,
         panel =  function(x,y,...){
           panel.bwplot(x,y,..., pch = "|" )
           panel.points(x, mean(y, na.rm = TRUE), pch = 3,col = "red",...)
         })

p2 <- bwplot(mpg ~ factor(vs) | factor(cyl), data = df_1, 
         groups=factor(vs), pch="|",
         panel = panel.superpose,
         panel.groups = function(x,y,...) {
           panel.bwplot(x,y,...)
           panel.points(x,mean(y, na.rm = TRUE), col = "red", pch = 3) 
         })
```

Output:

```
print(p1) # wrong mean values
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/m9rk6cdxyqp92tj/p1.png?dl=0

```
print(p2) # correct mean values
```

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mggehy7gst55trr/p2.png?dl=0

Comment: When in doubt, you could insert `browser()` into your `panel` or `panel.groups` function to see what data are used to calculate the statistics you're looking at. Otherwise, read the documentation of `xyplot`, especially focusing on the parts mentioning `groups[subscripts]`.

Comment: Thanks for the `browser()` tip @BenBarnes. It appears the `mean()` function calculates means for each **cyl** and ignores **vs**  in p1 wich causes wrong results. When using `panel.points()` **without mean()**, however, it does use **vs** as a "grouping factor" and plots the relevant points as expected and as does the `bwplot()` without `panel.superpose()`. After looking at the documentation, that still confuses me. Why does it recognize the data points described by the formula but can not pass them to the `mean()` function correctly?